# Гарантия НЕвыделения памяти

Tags: linux, rust

Есть демон для выполнения команд в условиях, когда целевой сервер уже полудохлый: кончилась память, дескрипторы, произошел еще какой-то сбой и даже bash запуститься не может.
В данный момент утилита написана на C с собственным аллокатором памяти (запасает заранее - когда всё в порядке и потом с уже полученным блоком работает).

Хочу переписать на rust для удобства расширения. Однако собственные аллокаторы пока в стандрт не вошли и использовать их не могу.

Задачи, которые нужно выполнять маленькие и мне достаточно будет памяти на стеке, без выделения в куче.
Собственно вопрос:
Как можно писать на rust-stable код, который гарантровано будет работать без доп. запросов памяти?

Comment: один из косвенных признаков вопроса, «выпадающего» из тематики сайта — если он подразумевает ответ «да/нет».

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, что тут можно что-то гарантировать. Все контейнеры используют кучу, в том числе строки и векторы. По-моему, гарантировать отсутствие кучи может только отсутствие `stdlib`: http://rurust.github.io/rust_book_ru/src/no-stdlib.html. 

Советую спросить на английском стеке - может кто-нибудь из разработчиков ответит.

Comment: Вопрос переформулировал так чтобы предполагался развёрнутый ответ. nostdlib доступно только в nightly, т.е. тоже пока не подходит.

Comment: Ну можно всегда использовать `Vec::with_capacity(usize)` и аналогичные конструкторы для контейнеров, чтобы заранее запасать нужное количество памяти.

Comment: Вообще в расте если ты явно не попросишь памяти конструктором, то она из кучи и не выделиться. Так что можно просто использовать только структуры и массивы на стеке, и никогда не использовать всякие Vec и Box, и таким образом получить ту самую гарантию не использования кучи. Но если уж нужна память неизвестного при компиляции размера, от кучи никуда не деться.

Comment: Из логических соображений это вроде понятно, но чтобы быть уверенным что всё так и есть нужно какое-то упоминание об этом в документации или например в требованиях к исходному коду.

Comment: Можно использовать сторонний аллокатор [TLSF](http://www.gii.upv.es/tlsf/).

Comment: Тут выходит изначальная проблема - использовать свой аллокатор можно только в ночных сборках. И интерфейс не признан стабильным. Это значит что если через 5 лет придется добавить сюда новую функцию и перекомпилировать бинарник - он может просто не скомпилироваться. Сам аллокатор написать это не проблема - для С версии так и сделано.